# Getting Max date from multiple table after INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the two following tables:

```
table 1)
ID |  HOTEL ID | NAME 
1       100      xyz 
2       101      pqr
3       102      abc
 

table 2)
ID | BOOKING ID | DEPARTURE DATE | AMOUNT
1         1       2013-04-12        100
2         1       2013-04-14        120
3         1       2013-04-9          90
4         2       2013-04-14        100
5         2       2013-04-18        150
6         3       2013-04-12        100
```

I want to get the following result in MySQL such that it takes the row from Table 2 with MAX DEPARTURE DATE:

```
ID | BOOKING ID | DEPARTURE DATE | AMOUNT
2         1       2013-04-14        120
5         2       2013-04-18        150
6         3       2013-04-12        100
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.ID,
        b.BookingID,
        a.Name,
        b.departureDate,
        b.Amount
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.BookingID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  BookingID, MAX(DepartureDate) Max_Date
            FROM    Table2
            GROUP   BY BookingID
        ) c ON  b.BookingID = c.BookingID AND
                b.DepartureDate = c.Max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc62e/3)

Answer (score -4):

Well,

```
SELECT * FROM `table2` ORDER BY `DEPARTURE_DATE` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

should help

Comment: I have to join two tables to get the reult

Comment: ID in first table is related to booking Id in second table