# How to get MAX date in INNER JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, join, max

I want to get the order status where status is logged in a separate table 'order_status_change'. Using following script, I was able to get all records but not the latest status. (Need status for order_item_ID for max(status change_date).

```
 SET @UserID = 160;
    SET @OrderDateTime = '2018-11-13 09:23:45';

    SELECT 
order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID,
order_price.ORDER_ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE,
order_status_change.ORDER_STATUS

FROM order_items 

INNER JOIN order_price ON order_price.ORDERP_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID

INNER JOIN order_status_change ON order_status_change.ORDER_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID

WHERE ((SELECT A.A_User_ID from A WHERE A.A_USER_ID = @UserID) AND (DATE(order_items.ORDER_REQUIRED_DATE_TIME) = DATE(@OrderDateTime)))
```

If I use Max(order_status_change.STATUS_CHANGE_DATE) then I get only one record. 
I modified the query by looking at a different example here but not working.

```
SELECT 
order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID,
order_price.ORDER_ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE,
order_status_change.ORDER_STATUS

FROM order_items 

INNER JOIN order_price ON order_price.ORDERP_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(order_status_change.ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME) AS STATUS_CHANGED_DATE FROM order_status_change WHERE order_status_change.ORDER_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID) 
AS order_status_change ON order_status_change.ORDER_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID

WHERE ((SELECT A.A_User_ID from A WHERE A.A_User_ID = @UserID) AND (DATE(order_items.ORDER_REQUIRED_DATE_TIME) = DATE(@OrderDateTime)))
```

How could I get the 'LATEST' order_status_change.STATUS for each order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID ?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What is the `chef` table relationship with other tables?

Comment: Your query is quite complicated and *possibly inefficient* due to multiple subqueries. Sample data and expected output would be helpful, and *maybe* query can be refactored. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Its simply get order_Items id using userID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Max date from multiple table after INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082238/getting-max-date-from-multiple-table-after-inner-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
    order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID,
    order_price.ORDER_ITEM_TOTAL_PRICE,
    order_status_change.ORDER_STATUS
FROM order_items 
INNER JOIN order_price ON order_price.ORDERP_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(order_status_change.ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME) AS STATUS_CHANGED_DATE,ORDER_ITEM_ID
    FROM order_status_change 
    GROUP BY ORDER_ITEM_ID
) AS order_status_change ON order_status_change.ORDER_ITEM_ID = order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID
WHERE (
    (DATE(order_items.ORDER_REQUIRED_DATE_TIME) = DATE(@OrderDateTime))
)
```

Comment: I get : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'order_items.ORDER_ITEM_ID' in 'field list'. I know field name is right.Typically this happens when INNER join is not right. Your query makes sense now than I have written. to get MAX date. The order that I pull ORDER_ITEM_ID fine to me but it can not see it.